# How to convert msft word RGB specification to ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a boxplot using ggplot2 while I am limited to using only specific colors. these specific color is provided in microsoft word, where I can find their RGB values. For example, there is a color with Red=204, Green=204, Blue=170. This suppose to be a color similar to coresilk2 or bisque2 (but not exactly) I have tried following code to set my color,

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue1", "#204204170", "204204170","#FF0000"))
```

it seems that ggplot2 only take 2 decimals for each R, G, and B scale and "#204204170", "204204170" did not work out at all (it returns a red color for "204204170", error message for "#204204170").

Can anyone help out with this issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You won't be needing Dodger Blue any more this season ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this helps:

```
rgb(red=204, green=204, blue=170, maxColorValue = 255)
[1] "#CCCCAA"
```

Comment: Is that saying in MSFT Word, the maximum value of RGB scale is 255? How can I find this max in word?